# having trouble reading in sound with java

Tags: java, audio

I am using Java sound to read in sound from the mic and transform it using fft. The issue I am having is that when I examine the byte array after the call to soundline.read() returns, it only contains 0,1, and -1. I am thoroughly confused. Below is my code:

```
private void setupSound() {
    Vector<AudioFormat> formats = getSupportedFormats(TargetDataLine.class);

    try {
        float sampleRate = 44100;
        int sampleSizeInBits = 16;
        int channels = 1;
        int frameSize = 2;
        boolean signed = false;
        boolean bigEndian = false;
        format =  new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED, sampleRate, sampleSizeInBits, channels, frameSize, sampleRate, bigEndian);
        soundLine = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getTargetDataLine(format);
        soundLine.open(format);
        soundLine.start();
    } catch (LineUnavailableException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
}

private byte[] readSoundSample() {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[44100];
    int len = soundLine.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
    return buffer;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean when you say the buffer contains only 1, 0 and -1. How are you looking at it. The reason I ask is that `byte` is unsigned so can't contain negative values.

Comment: I am looking at it through Netbeans debug. I dont understand what is going on. Id think that sound data would be a variety of values, not just three

Comment: My point was that you're looking at a byte and it shows you a value of -1 then something is amiss - because byte is unsigned. You should convert the bytes into shorts and have a look.

Comment: also byte is signed, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html